# AMORE - Neural network training "with teacher" for two input variables

Tags: r, neural-network

I have very silly problem, but it is still a problem.
I wanted to train a neural network with two input data sets "P1", "P2" and "T" as a result.
I know how do this thing if there is only "x1" but I can't manage it with two variables. Here is my code, it draws a 3d plot of input data (x1,x2,y) but only 2d plot of output data. I hope I've explained it correctly.

```
library(AMORE)

P1 <- Dane02[,1]
P2 <- Dane02[,2]
T <- Dane02[,3]

target <- T    

net <- newff(n.neurons=c(2,20,10,1), learning.rate.global=0.01,
             momentum.global=0.01, error.criterium="LMS", 
             Stao=NA, hidden.layer="tansig", 
             output.layer="purelin", method="ADAPTgdwm")

result <- train(net, P1, P2, target, error.criterium="LMS", 
                report=TRUE, show.step=100, n.shows=100 )

y <- sim(result$net, P1, P2)

library(rgl)
plot3d(P1,P2,target)
points3d(P1,P2,y, col="red")
```

As it is shown on picture below, it looks like it is training the network thinking that "P2" is target. Am I correct? How can I correct it? [image: Shoot from two different angles. You see red plot is flat]

Result after corrects:
[image: Result]

Comment: The third argument of `train` is the target: you are predicting `P2` from `P1`
(and `T` is used for validation). 
The following may work:
`train(net, P=Dane02[,1:2], T=Dane02[,3])`.

Comment: Thank your it works well. Now i have a little bit different question now i'm trying to adjust parameters of this network to learn good. Do you have some tips how to change this values that network could solve this problem?

Comment: From the plot, the function you are trying to approximate looks rather regular: two large hidden layers may be overkill -- one hidden later with, say, 5 neurons, may be sufficient.

Comment: Second time Your advice was very useful I was trying even `(2,40,30,1)` network and `show.step=1000, n.shows=1000` and it was taking ages to get it done, now i changed parameters to `(2,6,1)` and `show.step=100, n.shows=100 learning.rate.global=0.0001` and it works briliant :D thank You very much in my first post I've added picture what i get now. Thank You again

Comment: I do not see how this is related to RStudio, so I removed the tag.